# catch nullpointerexception in jsp fails

Tags: java, jsp

This code is written to catch a nullpointerexception

```
<%@page import="model.Personne"%>
<%
    Personne p;
    try {
        p = (Personne) request.getAttribute("test");
    } catch (NullPointerException e) {
        out.print("<p>Exception catched " + e.getMessage() + "</p>");
        p = new Personne();
        p.name = "Albert";
    }
%>
```

But it doesn't catch the error as shown by Glassfish log:

```
Warning:   StandardWrapperValve[jsp]: Servlet.service() for servlet jsp threw     exception
java.lang.NullPointerException
at org.apache.jsp.newjsp_jsp._jspService(newjsp_jsp.java:69)
```

About Personne, it is a very simple class, just for the test.

Comment: What about preventing `null` to begin with?

Answer (score 2):

The line

```
p = (Personne) request.getAttribute("test");
```

will **not** throw a `NullPointerException` but `p` will simply be null if the request does not contain an attribute `test`. So your catch block is not executed and you run into a `NullPointerException` later on, when you use the null `p`.

Answer (score 0):

A null pointer exception occurs when you invoke a instance method or attribute. In the line:

```
p = (Personne) request.getAttribute("test");
```

The only instance is "request" and it never will be null.

Your logic must be something like this:

```
Personne p;
p = (Personne) request.getAttribute("test");
if (p == null) {
    p = new Personne();
    p.name = "Albert";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this simple example and you'll see that the `NullPointerException` will be caught:

```
<%
    try {
        String p = null;
        out.print(p.toString());
    } catch (NullPointerException e) {
        out.print("<p>Exception catched " + e.getMessage() + "</p>");
    }
%>
```

Like wero stated I assume that the NPE is thrown later.

Answer (score 0):

You can use JSTL Core  Tag in your jsp page.
Here is the example

```
 <%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
<html>
<head>
<title><c:catch> Tag Example</title>
</head>
<body>

<c:catch var ="catchException">
<%    Personne p; 
p = (Personne) request.getAttribute("test"); %>
</c:catch>

<c:if test = "${catchException != null}">
   <p>The exception is : ${catchException} <br />
   <%  p = new Personne();
       p.name = "Albert"; %>
</c:if>

</body>
</html>
```

[Here is the Referencce](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/jsp/jstl_core_catch_tag.htm)